# A four way categorical variable with a frequency, what is the best solution? Chi-square or something else?

Tags: chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics

We are doing research to see if images quality affects engagement.
We are doing this for 3 products.
We are doing this for 4 image quality levels.
And for each of them we are checking the engagement in form of a frequency count.

Would it be correct to assume that the data should be processed with a chi-square?
Like so

[image: Table 1: Three product categories on top, with 4 image quality level on the left]

If this is true, is there any way I could also analyse each individual category with the four levels? What Descriptives could I use for that?

[image: Table 2: Individual analysis possible for data like this?]

Answer (score 3):

One reason that a chi-square test of association may not be appropriate is that categories need to be mutually exclusive and exhaustive. I imagine that's not really the situation you have here, but it's not clear from your description.  Also,  chi-square doesn't recognize that Quality is really ordinal in nature, but treats it as nominal categorical.  It may be advantageous to use a technique that treats Quality as ordinal.

It's not clear to me if you want to compare the results across the Products, or if you want to treat each Product separately. If your data are real, the trend for Speaker is opposite that for Coffee. Is this the kind of thing you want to test for explicitly?

I'll offer one potential solution.  Here, I'll assume you want to look at each Product separately.  Looking at one product, you could use the one-sample sign test to determine if the counts of Quality 1 or 2 are higher than those for 3 or 4 for that Product.

```
if(!require(DescTools)){install.packages("DescTools")}
library(DescTools)

Speaker = c(67, 42, 41, 30)

Table = as.table(Speaker)

dimnames(Table) = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

Counts = as.data.frame(Table)

Long = Counts[rep(row.names(Counts), Counts$Freq), c("Var1")]

median(as.numeric(Long))

   ### [1] 2

SignTest(as.numeric(Long), mu = 2.5)

   ### One-sample Sign-Test
   ### S = 71, number of differences = 180, p-value = 0.005668
   ### alternative hypothesis: true median is not equal to 2.5
```

See also: [This question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/343199/is-a-chi-squared-goodness-of-fit-test-applicable-in-this-situation)

Comment: What an elaborate answer thanks. So the question we are trying to answer is does image quality matter, does it have an affect across the three products. Like you say for the first and second the affect is indeed opposite. To me it means that for these products it appears people have different preferences. I just don't know how to test this across as a whole (all three categories) and on an individual level (per category).

Comment: Because the effect is not the same across the Products, you shouldn't just pool the results across Products to find an overall effect. The simplest approach is to treat each Product separately, and then make conclusions between Products by eyeball.  In the case of the data you presented, clearly there's a trend one way for Speaker, the other way for Coffee, and no trend for Phone.  If you want to tease this out statistically, probably the right approach is to use ordinal regression, something like `clm(Count ~ Product)`.  But a lot of the story is told by the proportion of counts.

Answer (score 0):

Are the observations independent? Then you could use chi-square. If they are not. Then you have a dependency you need to control for. Mcnemar could be used or a multilevel multinominal regression is an option.